Selenium remote driver is giving error with proxy authentication
I am trying to launch a browser in BitBAr from my IDE setup. I have to bypass the proxy and then connect to remote server. After doing some google & stackoverlow help I wrote this code. But it does not seem to work with Java 11 but it connects the remote browser with Java 8. Can someone please help as I have spent lot of time undertanding the issue byt failed to get the solution
Selenium version used - 4.21.1 (used previous ones also)
Jave version (11)
The errors I get are
getMessage(): Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response:
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read:
Extract of the code, cannot share the proxy and key details, so have kept some
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoSuchFieldException {
        MutableCapabilities capabilities = new MutableCapabilities();
        
        // SET PROXY DETAILS
        String proxyHost = "someurl.com";
        int proxyPort = 8080;
        String proxyUser = "proxyUSer";
        String proxyPassword = "proxyPassword";
        String remoteDesktopURL = "https://us-west-desktop-hub.bitbar.com/wd/hub/";
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
        ClientConfig config = null;

        // CONFIG TO ADD CREDENTIALS
        try {
            config = ClientConfig.defaultConfig()
                    .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(90))
                    .authenticateAs(new UsernameAndPassword(proxyUser, proxyPassword))
                    .proxy(proxy)
                    .baseUrl(new URL(remoteDesktopURL));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "macOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserVersion", "120");

        //Setting BITBAR capabilities
        HashMap<String, String> bitbarOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
        bitbarOptions.put("apiKey", "someKey");
        bitbarOptions.put("osVersion", "12");
        bitbarOptions.put("resolution", "2560x1920");
        bitbarOptions.put("seleniumVersion", "4");
        bitbarOptions.put("bitbar_testTimeout", "1800");

        // Creating a RemoteWebDriver instance with Bitbar capabilities
        try{
            driver = RemoteWebDriver.builder()
                    .config(config)
                    .oneOf(capabilities)
                    .setCapability("bitbar:options", bitbarOptions)
                    .build();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/"); ```

 

